# Let $E:y^2 = x^3 + 1$ be an elliptic curve. For each prime $5 \leq p \leq 13$, describe the group $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

$$\Large\textbf{Problem}$$
Let $E:y^2 = x^3 + 1$ be an elliptic curve.   For each prime $5 \leq p \leq 13$, describe the group $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$, the Mordell-Weil group.

$$\Large\textbf{Attempts and Ideas}$$
I am having lots of thoughts about this problem, so I jot them down.

Since $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a nonempty group, the identity $\infty$ (this is how my professor defines the identity in Mordell-Weil group) must be in $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$.

For any prime $p$ such that $5 \leq p \leq 13$, we see that there is a point of order $2$ in the group $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ since there exists $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $0 = x^3 + 1$ holds.

It remains to determine the points of finite order $n \geq 2$.  If $E:y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$, then

$$\mathrm{Discr}_E = -4a^3b + a^2b^2 + 18ab - 4b^3 - 27c^2$$

Since $a = b = 0$ and $c = 1$, $\mathrm{Discr}_E = -27$.  The strong form of Nagell-Lutz Theorem tells us that if $\beta^2 | -27$ and $(\alpha, \beta) \in E(\mathbb{F}_p)$, then $\beta \in \{\pm 1, \pm 3\}$.  Write

$$\beta^2 = \alpha^3 + 1$$

We need to check if there are points of finite order.  If $\beta = \pm1$, then $
\alpha$ does not exist since it does not belong to $\mathbb{F}_p$ for any prime $5 \leq p \leq 13$ (at this point $\alpha = 0 \not\in \mathbb{F}_p$).  If $\beta = \pm 3$, then $\alpha^3 = 8$, which implies $\alpha = 2$.

Overall, $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ consists of $\infty$, the point of order $2$ and two points of order $4$ (I believe that this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$).

$$\Large\textbf{Notes}$$

This problem is similar to ["The Group of points of Elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305157/the-group-of-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x31-over-mathbbf-5), but different since the given problem asks me to describe the group for prime $5 \leq p \leq 13$ (hopefully not a duplicate!).

Other than that, leave comments/answers/thoughts about the details I posted here.

Comment: I suppose the first question is whether you need to find all the points by bruteforcing $\mathbb F_p\times \mathbb F_p$. If not, you will need to know that you have indeed found all of them. If you do not have access to [Hasse's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves), this seems quite hard to do. If you do bruteforce, at that point you are basically reduced to a group theory problem and it seems natural to just continue with group theoretic computations. You might want to also note that if $(x,y)\in E(\mathbb F_p)$ then $(x, p-y)\in E(\mathbb F_p)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take for instance $p=5$. The curve $E: y^2=x^3+1$ has good reduction at $5$, so $E/\mathbb{F}_5$ is an elliptic curve, in particular, $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is a finite abelian group. You can easily find all the points of $E$ in $\mathbb{P}^2(\mathbb{F}_5)$, and verify that there are $6$ points (counting the point at infinity). Since $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is finite abelian of order $6$, it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, you can also verify that $P=(2,3)$ is a generator, with
$$2P=(0,1),\ 3P=(4,0),\ 4P=(0,4),\ 5P=(2,2),$$
and $6P=\infty$. You can work out the structure of $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$, for any $p>3$ in a similar way. For example, you can verify that $E(\mathbb{F}_7)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, or that $E(\mathbb{F}_{17})\cong \mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I might add that this kind of hands-on pencil-and-paper computation is invaluable for gaining understanding and intuition.

Comment: @Lubin, completely agree!